# Using Point() in my query results in strange results, am i using it wrong or is this to be expected?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, geolocation, spatial

In MySQL Workbench I have a column for Latitude and Longitude and I would like to convert them to point() in order to use that data in a map on Data Tools (SSRS report). I have created a column with the geometry datatype like so:

```
CREATE Table alabama_table2 (StateName varchar(64),City varchar(64),SpatialData geometry)
```

And I have the following code for inserting the data

```
INSERT INTO alabama_table2
select (StateName,City,POINT(NewLatitude,NewLongitude)
From alabama_table
Group By City;
```

However my results come back in this weird format which I don't think is correct

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [convert your internal geo format to text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetching-spatial-data.html). Use

SELECT ... ST_AsText(geometry)

to retrieve human readable versions of your geometric data items.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This is exactly the correct answer. :)